# Typescript: correlation between a field and the type of a function's parameter

Tags: typescript

I am developing a generic component for creating tables given the configuration of the columns.

Each row of the table is represented by a data model:

```
export interface Item {
  field1: string,
  field2: {
    field21: number,
    field22: {
      field221: string;
      field222: string;
    },
  },
}
```

The configuration of table columns is done using the ColumnsType type.

```
type Magic<T> = any; // The type of the value extracted with the path

export interface ColumnType<T> {
  path: Paths<T>, // 'field1' | 'field2' | 'field2.field21' | 'field2.field22' | 'field2.field22.field221' | 'field2.field22.field222' 
  format?: (value: Magic<T>) => string,
}

export type ColumnsType<T> = Array<ColumnType<T>>;
```

- **path** is used to extract the cell value from the row.
- **format** is the function that formats the value deduced from the row through the variable path

Column configuration:

```
export const itemsColumns: ColumnsType<Item> = [
  {
    path: 'field1',
  },
  {
    path: 'field2',
    format: ({field21, field22}) => field21 > 0 ? field22.field221 : field22.field221
  },
  {
    path: 'field2.field22',
    // format: ({field221, field222}: Item['field2']['field22']) => `${field221} - ${field222}`,
    format: ({field221, field222}) => `${field221} - ${field222}`,
  },
];
```

**Question**

1. How do I create the type alias Magic? Without defining the type in the configuration eg. Item ['field2'] ['field22']

Thank you very much

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAblAvFA2gOyROAaKABgIEYCAmAgZgIBYCBWAgNgIHYCAOAgTlOKgkygyoJqD6gpoNaCOg7oL5RyAgHQbC6ALraAsAChDoSFABSAewCWmADwBpAjAB8qKPagQAHsAiYAJgDOUIHAcDYA5lAAPlCYAK4AtgBGuIZQUAD8sJ4+fkEhYZExcUmpcOkZWVAABgAkAN72AL6NAORtub4BwTDVHVAAXFBtam2tDTDNNZUZw9iIaQZzcThwANyGht5gFnDAUCbQMACGwAAWgbYAKgQAIl35wQkpuG4khK5o6Hfajz0YBa4fTLapAiqg4bXf4FCzJABWEAAxsBKtkGpV0B4bFAANYQEAWABmUGu2gAtJlhh5vN0CqFwpgorEXuVZlUMtl6k1piVLDYHE4zpcbljtE4EIgftpnM52Rz5mtNqCMs10PjCSSyZVhh1ldsvLt9lAbL44ESTkjoABJXyJKAY0FEqwQAA2-hIwwZkTwlWdbv85GGjo5-vd5E9pVe+HZYcDQYd8qgcfIEa9RSZvpVVRTqfTjIiWY5zSLUBLhmaWwMRygAFkThErEibl9SeqCcTSX8APTd5MnKyuiD+KBnO1gVFGAw7PYHU24C1WqAAYQsrqSmGu4AgLcToLAwuGpwuV2uzlLRL2iTOVKgAApECd1xBhvXG82zwBKVCub2ZqAVlWM7GjWq7rokmCBFukC7mgACCcBwCcIC2GBG7QTuZ7OPq06GrOUBIhYkFznagRoRBgTDORkEYbYtoQIkrboJUIZVAeFy6nGJBtKW5agqxGTsecnEuuGPGxleZzDHeDQpsIubNN+KCuHJUCuIQ1S5mouYkEMyaifG2kGamJCVHxGQCVAQkiQG5BGbZ5Didml5wNewDSbJxkRgQubkIpP61I0OnNFA5JQEFXl+TUvFZtoypAA4)

Comment: So you don't care about the constraint between `path` and `format`?  No matter how you define `Magic<T>`,  `Magic<Item>` wouldn't know about `path`.  So you'd be able to write `{path: 'field1', format: ({field221}=>"")}` and the compiler wouldn't have a problem with it.  If that's okay, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrvGzN) is a possible solution.  If that works for you, I'll write it up.  If that *doesn't* work for you, then please consider editing this question to be very explicit about acceptable/unacceptable code.  Let me know.

Comment: If you *do* care about correlation between `path` and `format`, then maybe you prefer [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/N9JpMm) instead.  Here, `ColumnType<T>` is a union of all actually possible `path`/`format` pairings.  If you'd prefer this answer, I'll write it up instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, i do care about correlation between `path` and `format`, the title and the comment on the alias type Magic are misleading I will edit immediately thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `path` and `format` properties of `ColumnType<T>` to be correlated, then you can't do it where `ColumnType<T>` is a single `interface`; in your definition:

```
export interface ColumnType<T> {
  path: Paths<T>, 
  format?: (value: Magic<T>) => string,
}
```

the `Paths<T>` type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of *all* possible dotted paths from `T`, and
no matter what `Magic<T>` is, there's no way for it to *depend* on pieces of `Paths<T>`.

What you really want is for `ColumnType<T>` to *itself* be a union of `path`/`format` pairs, for each `path` in `Paths<T>`. This implies that we should forget about separate `Paths<T>` and `Magic<T>` types, and try to build them together.

Here's one possible solution:

```
// Join<K, P> prepends key K to path P with a dot 
//   (unless either K or P are empty)
type Join<K, P> = K extends string | number
  ? P extends string | number
  ? `${K}${'' extends P ? '' : '.'}${P}`
  : never
  : never;

// PathFormat<P, V> is the path/format pair for path P and value V
type PathFormat<P, V> = { path: P, format?: (value: V) => string }

// PrependToPathFormat<K, PF> takes a key K and an existing
//   PathFormat PF and produces a new PathFormat where the key K
//   is prepended to the path
type PrependToPathFormat<K, PF> =
  PF extends PathFormat<infer P, infer V> ? PathFormat<Join<K, P>, V> : never

// ColumnType<T> is the union of PathFormat<K, T[K]> for 
//  every key K in keyof T and, recursively, the result of prepending K 
//  to the PathFormat union from ColumnType<T[K]>
type ColumnType<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]-?:
  PathFormat<K, T[K]> | (PrependToPathFormat<K, ColumnType<T[K]>>)
}[keyof T] : never
```

The idea here is that `ColumnType<T>` will be a union of `PathFormat<K, T[K]>` for each key `K` and value `T[K]` in `T`, together with a transformed version of `ColumnType<T[K]>`.

---

Let's look at an example:

```
interface SimpleObject { c: number, d: boolean }
type ColumnTypeSimple = ColumnType<SimpleObject>;
// type ColumnTypeSimple = 
//  PathFormat<"c", number> | 
//  PathFormat<"d", boolean>

interface NestedObject { a: string, b: SimpleObject }
type ColumnTypeNested = ColumnType<NestedObject>;
// type ColumnTypeNested = 
//  PathFormat<"a", string> | 
//  PathFormat<"b", SimpleObject> | 
//  PathFormat<"b.c", number> | 
//  PathFormat<"b.d", boolean>
```

You can see that `ColumnType<SimpleObject>` is the union of `PathFormat` types for the `c` and `d` properties of `SimpleObject`.  And `ColumnType<NestedObject>` is the union of `PathFormat` types for the `a` and `b` properties of `NestedObject`, as well as `ColumnType<SimpleObject>` transformed so that the paths `"c"` and `"d"` become `"b.c"` and `"b.d"` respectively.

---

So now we can test your `itemsColums` code, which works:

```
const itemsColumns: ColumnsType<Item> = [
  {
    path: 'field1',
  },
  {
    path: 'field2',
    format: ({ field21, field22 }) => field21 > 0 ? field22.field221 : field22.field221
  },
  {
    path: 'field2.field22',
    format: ({ field221, field222 }) => `${field221} - ${field222}`,
  },
]; // okay
```

and we will also catch errors where the `path` or `format` are incorrect or do not match each other:

```
const badItemsColumns: ColumnsType<Item> = [
  { path: "field3" }, // error! 
  //~~~~ <--
  //Type '"field3"' is not assignable to type 
  //'"field1" | "field2" | "field2.field21" | "field2.field22" |
  //"field2.field22.field221" | "field2.field22.field222"'.

  { path: "field2.field21", format: (({ field222 }) => "") }, // error!
  // ---------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~
  // Property 'field222' does not exist on type 'Number'.
];
```

---

**PLEASE NOTE** that such mapped recursive types can have weird edge cases, so you should definitely test it out fully to see that it meets your use cases.  Depending on the type `T` passed in to `ColumnType<T>`, you could get weird output, or even hit recursion limits or performance problems with the compiler.  There are ways to try to mitigate these, but addressing all of them in advance is out of the scope of a single Stack Overflow question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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-2Q1DX05KEv2g5KKLowDRNYz9qM1Ljcjk6AZLnbTnV2YgVCNWWzkAIKEIQnAMMgXUUTglnkqqNZBDB91UIZVA9BLjV3RYsKtuMIP428vA9PUiMffUFOktrSuSiriK9BrANa6jqLcBi8LG+9mDGwDpL4oSBMQ1DkB4AADLGztI30dvvRMdu+4TUPjFToN63IBtq8bQcuyb2sI0ylvexjNsp0T9s1I7eAVJUfs1JAiGQFUdsA6M2thx2SyQLIsC0FzgvC1IcScBQsvmOLDOS5VX5M8+7fy4rCI9B5GsAMweTrNdQLoN6EAAhL2cgQAAfmvK+QMgiGIeMEDab0o-oxPTQWogkiiBo8ChIgnBxE5J7FgfGvvZPUSHy7r+QO-gOx4DL+RF-GOdtX67zAN-SGv8MaQKJv-N+QDg7QKJh5fo5I5DwijoAwm0CX62yTpAeQ8grbB0ztnL+Hl8Tk2nmYDmhh56gMLtvRhTDmEsNYcwvA69OEr3oXhWAZBCDWCNsQpoEgNRnykD4UUBhhQVXqIlWGKCQBVyAA)